# Complex inequality in Rudin

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

I assume I'm going to end up slapping my forehead after I see the answer to this, but here goes:  in Baby Rudin, Example 5.18 is a demonstration that L'Hopital's rule doesn't hold for functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$.  I follow the reasoning well enough, except for one silly inequality:  he asserts that 
\begin{align}
\left|1 + \left\lbrace 2x - \frac{2i}{x}\right \rbrace e^{i/x^2}\right| \geq \left|2x - \frac{2i}{x}\right|-1
\end{align}
when $x \in (0,1)$.

I don't see why this is true.  It would be nice to apply the triangle inequality, but it doesn't seem to help:  we get 
\begin{align}
1 + \left|2x - \frac{2i}{x}\right| \geq \left|1 + \left\lbrace 2x - \frac{2i}{x}\right \rbrace e^{i/x^2}\right|,
\end{align}
which seems tantalizing but useless.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In any metric space we have $d(x,y) \geq |d(x,z) - d(z,y)| \geq d(x,z) - d(z,y)$ for all $x,y,z$ in the metric space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about the reverse triangle inequality:
$$
\lvert \lvert z_1 \rvert - \lvert z_2 \rvert \rvert \leq \lvert z_1-z_2 \rvert,
$$

where $z_1 = \left( 2x - \frac{2i}{x} \right) e^{i/x^2}$ and $z_2 =-1$.

Answer (score 0):

If we continue further in the Reverse triangle inequality

$$ \overbrace{\left| \underbrace{2x - \frac{2 i}{x}}_{\text{complex number with the real part 2x}} \right| \underbrace{\left| e^{i/x^2} \right|}_{1}}^{\text{range is (0,2)}} -1 $$

because of **Theorem 1.33d on page 14**

$$ |z| \ge |Re(z)|$$ and as $x \in (0,1)$